# Can't run PFP Growth with Mahout 0.7 (fpg file is empty)

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

I'm working on a load balanced version of PFP Growth on hadoop using mahout. I tried running PFPgrowth like this :

/usr/local/mahout/bin/mahout fpg -i /user/hduser/Data/retail.txt -o patterns -k 50 -method mapreduce -g 10 -regex [\ ]

But got this error: Unknown program 'fpg' chosen. I found the fpg.props file here: mahout/src/conf but it is empty, I think it is why it isn't working but where can I get the original version? is there any way I can run it on mahout 0.7 or has it been removed ? Thanks a lot.